# Getting the text of a selected option when another select is changed

Tags: jquery, html-select

If you would see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/UTjbm/1/

I want it so that when the second select tag is changed, an alert will appear with whatever the first selects option text is.

With what I have researched so far, I was hoping that would work, but alas, it does not. I am using jquery.

My jsfiddle code:

```
<select id="select_a">
  <option value='1'>woot1</option>
  <option value='2'>woot2</option>
  <option value='3'>woot3</option>
  <option value='4'>woot4</option>
</select>
<select id="select_b">
  <option value='1'>notwoot1</option>
  <option value='2'>notwoot2</option>
  <option value='3'>notwoot3</option>
  <option value='4'>notwoot4</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#select_b").change(function (){
  alert($("#select_a").options[$("#select_a").selectedIndex].text);
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are calling `.options` on a jQuery object which is wrong

You can do this -

```
$("#select_b").change(function (){
  alert($("#select_a option:selected").text());
});
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/UTjbm/6/

Answer (score 7):

**$("#select_a")** is a **jQuery object**

And you are trying to access it like a `DOM` element.. try this syntax

```
alert($("#select_a")[0].options[$("#select_a")[0].selectedIndex].text);
```

`.options` is a property available for a `DOM` object ..

So when you try to **apply it to a jQuery Object it throws a Syntax error.**

To convert a jQuery Object to a `DOM object` you can do

`$("#select_a")[0]` **or** `$("#select_a").get(0)` And then apply the corresponding DOM methods on it.

Or simple using pure jQuery you can do this

```
$("#select_a option:selected").text()
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UTjbm/5/)**

Comment: thanks a bunch, mate. I'll accept pXL's answer only because it was 7 seconds faster. Thanks a lot, though.